# modulus operator to run 1st and then every 3rd item

Tags: php, modulo, modulus

So i need it to run on the first loop and then every 3rd loop

```
if ($k % 3 || $k==1 ) { echo '<div class="modcontainer">'; }
```

Seems simple to me, but i don't have the understanding of modulus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modulus returns the remainder, not a boolean value.

This code will resolve to `true` for `1, 3, 6, 9, ...`

```
if (($k % 3 == 0) || $k==1 ) { echo '<div class="modcontainer">'; }
```

This code will resolve to `true` for `1, 4, 7, 10, ...`

```
if ($k % 3 == 1) { echo '<div class="modcontainer">'; }
```

Comment: @Waygood possibly, I'm not entirely sure if OP means `1, 3, 6, 9` or `1, 4, 7, 10`

Comment: hey, ye sorry it'd be 1,4,7,10