# Divide php echo rows into 3 columns

Tags: php, html, css

How do I get the database items coming from 1 SQL table and divide them in 3 separate columns (html divs) using php

[image]

Comment: Looks like your image does not exist.

Comment: depends if they are separate columns in the table, or if you need to split one value apart.  Your question needs to be a little more specific.

Comment: When you say split into three columns, how do you want to split it. For example we have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, will 1,4,7 be in the same column, or will 7,8,9 be in one column?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261192/modulus-operator-to-run-1st-and-then-every-3rd-item

Comment: I would like it to be left to right i.e. 123 and then a row below with 456 etc.

Answer (score 1):

here is a little example:

```
<?php

$result=array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');
$colon=3;//how much div
$divid=ceil(count($result)/$colon);//how much per div

for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++){
  if($x%$divid!=0){ 
    echo ' '.$result[$x];
   }else{ 
    echo ($x==0)? '<div>'.$result[$x]:'</div><div>'.$result[$x];
   }  
}
echo '</div>';

?>
```